# Xcode 4 not adjusting text size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I have a label that changes depending on what my rss parser sends it, and i want it to only be two lines, so I checked the "adjust to fit" box in the attributes inspector, but that is not adjusting the text to fit the box. it just truncates it at the end. I was wondering if there was any way to do this in the code itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if this works for you:

```
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```